# Redcarpet & Middleman: :with_toc_data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, markdown, middleman, redcarpet

I'm wondering about using Redcarpet's [:with_toc_data](https://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet#darling-i-packed-you-a-couple-renderers-for-lunch-) option for Markdown working with [Middleman](http://www.middlemanapp.com) (a Sinatra-based static site generator).

Our current **config.rb**:

```
set :markdown, :layout_engine => :haml
set :markdown_engine, :redcarpet
```

This doesn't work:

```
set :markdown, :layout_engine => :haml, :with_toc_data => true
set :markdown_engine, :redcarpet
```

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: That should work. File a ticket and we'll get some tests in place.

Comment: FWIW I'm very interested in this too, stumbled upon this issue in order to enable `fenced_code_blocks` - will report my findings in favor or against the success their of.

Comment: Filed a ticket per Thomas' request: https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in Middleman 3.0 by [Thomas Reynolds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/904346/thomas-reynolds): https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/442

Answer (score 1):

It appears that from [Issue #200](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/200) of Middleman at Github, this should be done as such:

```
set :markdown, :layout_engine => :haml
set :markdown_engine, :redcarpet
set :redcarpet, :with_toc_data => true
```

The third line being the key. I also can't make this work, so there might be something still open as a bug with Middleman?

The [latest release](http://rubygems.org/gems/middleman/versions/2.0.15.3-x86-mingw32) is `2.0.15.3`, which is what I have installed; but I also can't make it work. Perhaps [Issue #200](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/200) should be re-opened?

I have this exact code in my `config.rb`:

```
###
# GitHib flavoured Markdown, I can't go back!
###
set :markdown_engine, :redcarpet
set :redcarpet, fenced_code_blocks: true, autolink: true
```

I'd be eager to understand if I am doing something incorrectly. (I'm specifically trying to use this in a Middleman Blog)

**Update to my answer**: The commit referenced in [Issue #200](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/200) does not exist in the `2.0.15.3` release, thus we'll have to use something newer.

Comment: The above code (in my original question)should work, according to Thomas. Per his request, I [opened a Middleman issue](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/442).